# example of package 'ggtextures' in R didn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to use [ggtextures](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtextures) by [@Claus Wilke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4975218/claus-wilke) to create a barplot fill with different line style. But the example [here](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtextures) didn't work.

for example:

```
devtools::install_github("clauswilke/ggtextures")

library(ggtextures)
library(ggplot2)

images = c(
 compact = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/rocks2-256.jpg",
 midsize = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/stone2-256.jpg",
 suv = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/siding1-256.jpg",
`2seater` = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/mulch1-256.jpg",
 minivan = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/rocks1-256.jpg",
 pickup = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/wood3-256.jpg",
 subcompact = "http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/concrete1-256.jpg")

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, image = class)) +
  geom_textured_bar() +
  scale_image_manual(values = images)
```

error shows `Error: 'unitType' is not an exported object from 'namespace:grid'`.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: What versions of R and `grid` are you using? You can check with `sessionInfo()`

Comment: R 4.0.0 introduced more efficient unit operations and the `unitType()` function is an utility function to extract the type of unit (cm, inch, npc, native etc). If you're using R3.X then this function is not available to you because grid is included with the base distribution of R. Your example code runs fine on R4.0.0 for me.

Comment: Yeah this definitely is an R3.X issue, see https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtextures/issues/8

Comment: Thanks! It works after I updated R 3.6 to R 4.0